# What is the absolute intensity of the gamma radiation?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I was looking at the gamma radiation data from IAEA's website:

(https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html)

and was confused by the absolute intensity listed in the page. I Googled it and it seems to be the probability of emission but why it doesn't add up to one?[image]

Answer (score 2):

So that is Ba-133:  http://nucleardata.nuclear.lu.se/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=560133

There are gamma cascades, where the nucleus decays via one or more intermediate levels. So the average number of gamma-photons can be larger than unity.